# How to convert html special characters from an XML document in html

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I work with Google maps. The coordinates of points on a map and description of these points lie in an XML document. Some of the descriptions have html tags. In the derivation of the page - they are displayed as .
I understand that you need to replace < and > do it this function:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace) {
 return this.split(search).join(replace);
}
```

I use this:

```
 var text = points_array[i]['text'];
 text = text.replaceAll('&lt', "<");
 var text2 = text.replaceAll('&gt;', ">");
 jQuery("#about").text(text2);
```

As a result, all the same effect it does not. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use jquery `.html()` if you want the passed string to be treated as a HTML string otherwise it will always be interpreted as normal string of text